# Configuring Checkpoint VPN MacOS without Checkpoint client

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, checkpoint

Is there a way to connect to a Checkpoint VPN on a Mac without installing their client software?

I'm on OSX Ventura 13.0.1 with an M2 chipset. Their latest client [E86.50](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=123672) doesn't support Apple Silicon, so I'd need to install Rosetta to use it. Plus, their software wants to install a kext, filter all of my traffic, etc... kinda creepy.

Any suggestions?